# The Matrix, Resolution of the Source

Tags: the-matrix

Was [The One](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_One)'s code reinserted into The Matrix, thereby saving it from crashing at the end of *Matrix : Revolutions* or was this unnecessary as Smith and Neo are dead, thus stabilizing the code?

Did the Architect forget to mention the 3rd door hiding behind him through which events will unfold as we saw them or was he just misinformed, wrong or lying?

Comment: `Did the Architect forget to mention the 3rd door hiding behind him through which events will unfold` - what 3rd door?

Comment: He described the two different outcomes of walking through each door. Neither of which happens. @naxa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end of Revolutions, there's no need for The One's code to be reinserted into the Matrix.

The machines have agreed to end the war and dismantle the Matrix as well as actively working to free those humans who remain inside it. The problem of the "unbalanced equation" (e.g. that Neo was supposed to fix) has resolved itself, albeit in a very unexpected way.

It's clear that some people will struggle with the shock and will even actively resist being removed. As we can see from the (wholly canon) [Matrix Online](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Matrix_Online), after the events of 'Revolution' the machines and Zionians started by actively freeing the 1% that are already subconsciously aware of the Matrix and moved on from there.

The ultimate result of the failure to resolve the "systemic anomaly" in MXO (Matrix Online) was that eventually every single person left plugged into the matrix had godlike powers to influence their surroundings, at which point **everyone** has become aware of the unreality of their situation and is (at least in theory) able to be unplugged safely.

If you're interested in "*what happened next*", you can read the plotline of the Matrix Online game [here](http://mxostory.mxoemu.info/).

Comment: Is there cannon or evidence that implies (from the movies only, not sure what cannon you call that) That eventually more and more people become The One? "[eventually every person plugged in the matrix had godlike power]"

Comment: "A grand finale was planned where all online players were to be crushed; however, due to a server glitch, most players were disconnected before the final blow came. Because **developer level powers** had been given to all remaining players, the situation on PvP servers meant that players could kill each other with a single hit.[11]"

Comment: @Mazura - The Matrix is relatively unique in that the films aren't considered more canon than the animated feature, comics (for the most part) or games.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call the closing finale of MxO 'canon', even if most of the rest MxO plot *is* canon; the Wachowskis weren't in charge at that time anymore, and it's fairly reasonable to think that that event was meant to be an out-of-universe 'fun for goodbye' to the players.

Comment: @naxa - All the events of MxO are described as canon although you're right that the final moments were probably off-script. We certainly know that the Wachowski's ultimate plan was that all remaining humans would be informed that they're inside a computer system and made ready for extraction.

Comment: also, `the machines have agreed` ... `and dismantle the Matrix` - I don't recall this; I recall they've agreed to `peace`. The Architect, who wasn't the one who made the deal, later, and I consider this outside the agreement, kind of a side-effect, only says that those who `want out` will `be freed`.

Comment: It's made clear in the films and comics that many people are unable to leave the matrix but that the systemic anomaly will continue to increase if the One's code isn't reinserted. Obviously those that want to leave can leave immediately but eventually the system will be so corrupted that everyone inside will perceive the Matrix as unreal

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Neo's source code was re-inserted into the matrix after the machines destroyed zion so he could re-start the process of freeing people from the matrix. 
Reasoning :
Morpheus says that the one lived before and told free men that he would return. In addition, the architect points out that machines needed people to believe they had the choice to leave or stay in the matrix in order for them to accept the program. The architect also highlights that Neo is the 5th iteration of the one thus his re-insertion into the program is to begin the next resistance.